# How do I change the list of uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to use XMLHttpRequest to upload files to the server.  Here are the steps I would like the code to do:

1. List the file in a file list ul
2. Upload the file(s) while displaying a progress bar
3. When the file is completely uploaded, change the list item for that file to a link without the progress bar.  This is where I am having a problem.

Here is the HTML code I am working with:

```
<h1>Upload Files</h1>
<input type='file' name='doc_upload_field[][]' multiple='multiple' id='doc_upload_field' /> 
<ul id='filelist'></ul>
```

Here is the javascript code I am working with:

```
function transferFailed(evt) {
    alert("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}                       
function transferCanceled(evt) {
    alert("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}

var filelist = $('#filelist');//define where the list of files will go
var url = "/";

function handleFileSelect_inputfield(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object


  // run through each file individually.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {    

  var li = $("<li><strong>" + f.name + "</strong> (" + f.type  +") - " + f.size + " bytes <div class='progress_bar'><div class='percent'>&nbsp;</div></div></li>");
  filelist.append(li);//put the file in the filelist

  var formData = new FormData(); 
  formData.append(f.name, f);

  //upload through xmlhttprequest
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();           
  xhr.upload.li = li;
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      var percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);                     
      // Increase the progress bar length.
      if (percentLoaded < 100) {
        this.li.find(".progress_bar").addClass('loading');
        this.li.find(".percent").width(percentLoaded + '%');
      } 
    }               
  }, false);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    //uploading is complete                 
  }, false);        

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'text';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {                
    if (this.readyState==4){  
      if (this.status == 200) { 
          //console.log(this.response);
          console.log("finished=" + li);//returns as an object
          //console.log("filename=" + f.name);//error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined              
          //change the list item. Not working...
          this.li.find("li").html("<a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a>");                      
      }
    }
  };                                    
  xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data                     
  }     
}

document.getElementById('doc_upload_field').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect_inputfield, false);
```

Everything seems to be working, but when I want to change the list item, li, it is not recognizing it.  I am able to change the progress bar length by calling:

```
this.li.find(".progress_bar").addClass('loading');
this.li.find(".percent").width(percentLoaded + '%');
```

But when I want to change the list item:

```
this.li.find("li").html("<a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a>");
```

It does not work.

Does anyone know why it would find it when changing the progress bar, but not find it after it is uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
this.li.find("li")
```

looks for an `<li>` element **inside** the other `<li>` element.  There isn't one, so nothing happens.

I think that just

```
this.li.html("<a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a>");
```

should be what you want. <strike>Or you could just do this:</strike>

```
this.li = $("<li><a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a></li>");
```

*edit* oops no that won't work because you've stuck it in the DOM already.  But the first one should work.

*edit* — you've also got a closure-related problem (or scope-related; whatever).  What you can do is something like what you've already done for the "li" value.  Add another property for it to "xhr.upload":

```
xhr.upload.updated_li = "<a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a>";
```

Do that right where you set "xhr.updated.li".  Then, in the event handler, you can do:

```
  this.li.html(this.updated_li);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried the first and it did not work.  The error said, "Cannot call method 'html' of undefined". EDIT: tried it again and it worked.... thanks.

Comment: When I put the f.name in the link it does not work, the error says "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"  when I take it out I don't get errors.

Comment: Oh ok well you're having a closure-related problem; I didn't notice the `for` loop.  Hold on and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that and it gave me an error of "Cannot call method 'html' of undefined".

Comment: I changed it to xhr.updated_li = $("<a href='#'>" + f.name + "</a>"); and it worked.  Thank you again for your help.